# Finding the image of a ring homomorphism

Tags: group-theory, ring-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $A$ be a subring and $B$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. 
I'm trying to prove the second isomorphism theorem for ring, which state that $$A/(A \cap B) \cong (A+B)/B$$

So I have defined a map 
$$f: A \longrightarrow R/B$$
$$f(a) = a + B$$
clearly $f$ is a ring homomorphism.
Since $ker(f) = A \cap B$ , the result follow once I show that $im(f) =(A+B)/B$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

So 
\begin{align}
im(f) & = \{f(a) : a \in A\} & (1)\\
& = \{a + B : a \in A\} & (2) \\
& = \{a + b + B : a \in A, b \in B\} & (3) \\
& = (A + B)/B & (4)
\end{align}

question:

1. is this valid? (specifically (2) to (3))
2. is it true that $A/B \cong (A + B)/B$

Comment: 1. Because $0\in B$, in fact $B=B+B$, so $a+B=a+B+B$. 2. What does $A/B$ mean, unless $B\subseteq A$?

Answer (score 1):

1. yes, the proof works exactly like that.
2. well, yes: the notation "$A/B$" is only really used if $B\subset A$, i.e. if $A$ is a subring of $B$ or an ideal in $B$. In that case $A+B=A$, so your statement is trivially true.